Pullback of bundles on Hirzebruch surface
Let us consider the Hirzebruch surface (as $\mathbb P^1$ bundle) $\pi : X_e:=\mathbb P(\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^1} \oplus \mathcal O_{\mathbb P^1}(-e)) \to \mathbb P^1$ with $e \geq 0$.
Let $n \in \mathbb Z$. Can we say that $\pi^*(\mathcal O_{\mathbb P^1}(n))= \mathcal O_{X_e}(n,n)$, where that later means the line bundle corresponding to the divisor $nc_0+nf$ (where $c_0,f$ are generators of the picard group)?

No, because the pullback of any bundle from the base is trivial on all fibers.

@CraniumClamp, thanks. Is it $\mathcal O(n, o)$?

$\mathcal{O}(y,e,s)$ that’s right, depending on your basis for Pic.

Isn't the restriction of relative $\mathcal{O}(1)$ to a fiber $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(1)$? But it seems like it should be the trivial bundle if both comments from @CraniumClamp and Daniel are correct. I'm confusing...

@okaberintarou You are confused for no reason as the OP never talks about relative O(1)

@CraniumClamp Ah I got it, indeed the choice of generators for Pic matters.
